# Why react use Queue for update?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am reveiwing react.development.js code.
Why react use Queue for update?

extra : what is ****REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK**** object use for ?

Answer (score 1):

React is a lazy compilated framework. It listens reactions of DOM and writes changes to queue and operates it and change callbacks for running order and optimization.

For extra: It is React Dev Tools for browsers. It is optional, not mandatory.